How to convert a string into bytes in specific charset (encoding) using JavaScript?
I want to generate text bytes in various charsets (encodings), such as ISO-8859-1, Big5, UTF-8, UTF-16, etc., mostly for testing purposes (i.e. to make sure my app script can correctly handle the provided bytes in these charsets), which is almost like:
new TextEncoder(mycharset).encode(mystring)

Unfortunately TextEncoder only supports conversion of a string into UTF-8 bytes, which is unlike TextDecoder, which supports conversion of bytes in various charset into a string.
The behavior of TextEncoder is defined by the spec and is unlikely going to be changed in the future... Any folk know why there is the inconsistent behavior in both classes? And the way to do the job? (without manually providing a conversion table/map for all the target charsets)
TO REVIEWER: This issue is NOT a duplicate of the related question, which asks why the parameter of TextEncoder does not take effect, and the answer says that TextEncoder does not take a parameter by the spec.
This questions specifically asks for:

why the spec specified that TextEncoder not take a parameter, which is inconsistent with TextDecoder
HOW to perform the conversion as this question asked

Both are not asked and explained in the related question and answer.

According to this issue the logic for keeping only UTF-8 is that all the various Web APIs only accept UTF-8 as input. So there should be no need to produce other encodings for the Web APIs. This makes the API a lot simpler. Also, there is a goal to make everything UTF-8, so not providing tools to produce non-UTF-8 encodings make sense for the Web API. However it's clear this goal isn't reached yet and thus it makes sense to have a decoder in the platform.
As for how to perform such encodings, you can use the polyfill made Joshua Bell, which does have a NONSTANDARD_allowLegacyEncoding option.
To use the polyfill on modern browsers, you'd need to nullify the browser's TextEncoder though:
<script>
window.TextEncoder = window.TextDecoder = null;
</script>
<script src="PATH/TO/POLYFILL.js"></script>

Here I copy a snippet from a previous answer of mine:


(async () => {
  const text = `Some text with nice line endings\nand special characters like é and ü.`;
  const encoding = 'windows-1252'; // a.k.a ANSI

  const utf8_blob = new Blob([text], { endings: "native" });
  const utf_8_txt = await utf8_blob.text();

  const encoder = new TextEncoder(encoding, {
    NONSTANDARD_allowLegacyEncoding: true
  });
  const data = encoder.encode(utf_8_txt); // now `data` is an Uint8Array
  const encoded_as_ANSI = new Blob([data]);

  const read_as_ANSI = await readAsText(encoded_as_ANSI, encoding)
  console.log({ read_as_ANSI });
  const read_as_UTF8 = await encoded_as_ANSI.text();
  console.log({ read_as_UTF8 });
})();

function readAsText(blob, encoding) {
  return new Promise(res => {
    const reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = e => res(reader.result);
    reader.readAsText(blob, encoding);
  });
}
<script>window.TextEncoder = null;// force installation of the polyfill</script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/inexorabletash/text-encoding/lib/encoding-indexes.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/inexorabletash/text-encoding/lib/encoding.js"></script>




Thank you. However seeing source code of  the library, it's still arbitrarily providing encoding tables, which may be outdated as the project has been not maintained for many years. :(

What's your use case? And you can search for other encoding libraries, if I linked to it, it's just that I trust the author of that one.

As mentioned in OP, it requires explicitly generating bytes in a specific encoding. Although a arbitararily mapping can do the job, I 'd more prefer something that can make the browser do the encoding natively to save space and prevent a potential compatibility issue.

Then you can't. The browser may even not support any of the legacy encodings. You have to resort on a library. Also, that's not really an use-case, it's a requirement. Do you have a specific encoding you have to support? What will be done with these bytes later on?

@DannyLin Why do you expect the encoding that you want to use to change in the future? That rarely, if ever, happens

@Kaiido I would argue the presumption that browsers don't support legacy encodings is not true. In several contexts, such as form[accept-charset="big5"] (which is not obsolete in the current HTML spec), the browser is able to send encoded bytes from a specified string (e.g. 中文 to %A4%A4%A4%E5). It seems that the browsers actually support the legacy encodings natively, and it may be possible to take advantage of it in someway.

Is is not obsolete though? My reading of https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/forms.html#attr-form-accept-charset "If specified, the value must be an ASCII case-insensitive match for "UTF-8"." got me thinking it's actually dead-code and the specs only support UTF-8 here too.

I'm not going to explain all the details. I know that an encoding table or library can do the job, but it's kind of brute-force and not elegant. I'm asking if a more elegant way is possible, and will of course do it in some dirty way (which I can already think of a tons of) on my own if no one can answer.

You're right, I didn't see it on the doc of MDN. But I wonder the browser will still support it for a long time like many APIs, and would like a native aolution as long as it has not been really removed.

But even the specs do use tables. Joshua is one of the 2 main authors of that spec, I think he also did Chrome's implementation, so I'd trust his polyfill does about the right thing. Also, FWIW accept-charset has been removed in https://github.com/whatwg/html/issues/3097

@DannyLin here I made a tentative to tap into the browser's encoders, but this encodes to percent-encoding, and thus it's only a partial encoding, which may not be easy to parse (I suppose you could extract safe-characters before encoding). But note that even having a non-UTF-8 document is actually deprecated, so don't rely on this to work forever either.

@Kaiido Thank you for the illustration. Unfortunately the result is not correct. The big5 encoding of abc中文à should be abc%A4%A4%A4%E5&#224; while your result is abc%E4%B8%AD%E6%26%2365533%3B%26%2365533%3B.

That's the result of the browser's encoding (to percent-encoding) though. What's the # in your result?

@Kaiido This incorrect result is because the text is encoded as UTF-8 when passed as a string into the Blob constructor in the very first, and thus distorted when read as the target encoding. To pass it safely the text should be HTML escaped, and there are more escapings needed to prevent special characters from taking effect. See my answer for the revised version.

Thanks for @Kaiido's idea. After some tests I finally find a way to do it natively:


/**
 * Encode a string into bytes in the specified charset.
 *
 * @param {string} str - the string to encode
 * @param {string} [charset=UTF-8] - the target charset to encode into
 * @param {*} [replacement] - the replacement char for a non-encodable char,
 *     which should be a valid ASCII char. Empty string to replace with
 *     nothing. Falsy to throw an error instead.
 * @return {Promise<Uint8Array>} The encoded bytes.
 */
var encodeText = (() => {
  function escapeHtml(str) {
    const rv = [];
    for (let i = 0, I = str.length; i < I; i++) {
      const code = str.codePointAt(i);
      if (code > 0xFFFF) { i++; }
      rv.push(`&#${code};`);
    }
    return rv.join('');
  }

  function unescapeHtml(str, replacement) {
    return unescape(str).replace(/&#(?:(\d+)|x([\dA-Fa-f]+));/g, (_, dec, hex) => {
      if (hex) {
        return String.fromCharCode(parseInt(hex, 16));
      }
      if (typeof replacement === 'string') {
        return replacement;
      }
      throw parseInt(dec, 10);
    });
  }

  function byteStringToU8Array(bstr) {
    let n = bstr.length, u8ar = new Uint8Array(n);
    while (n--) { u8ar[n] = bstr.charCodeAt(n); }
    return u8ar;
  }

  async function encodeText(str, charset = "UTF-8", replacement = null) {
    // test if the charset is available
    try {
      new TextDecoder(charset);
    } catch (ex) {
      throw new RangeError(`Specified charset "${charset}" is not supported.`);
    }

    charset = charset.toLowerCase();

    // specially handle Unicode transformations
    // Available UTF names:
    // https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Encoding_API/Encodings
    if (['utf-8', 'utf8', 'unicode-1-1-utf-8'].includes(charset)) {
      return new TextEncoder().encode(str);
    } else if (['utf-16be', 'utf-16le', 'utf-16'].includes(charset)) {
      const littleEndian = !(charset === 'utf-16be');
      const u8ar = new Uint8Array(str.length * 2);
      const view = new DataView(u8ar.buffer);
      for (let i = 0, I = str.length; i < I; i++) {
        const code = str.charCodeAt(i);
        view.setUint16(i * 2, code, littleEndian);
      }
      return u8ar;
    }

    const frame = document.createElement("iframe");
    const markup = `<!DOCTYPE html><script data-text="${escapeHtml(str)}">
function escapeHtml(str) {
  return str.replace(/[&#%]/g, m => escape("&#x" + m.charCodeAt(0).toString(16) + ";"));
}
const text = escapeHtml(document.currentScript.dataset.text);
const a = document.createElement("a");
a.href = "https://example.com/?" + text;
parent.postMessage(a.search.slice(1), "*");
<\/script>`;
    const blob = new Blob([markup], {type: `text/html;charset=${charset}`});
    frame.src = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    document.body.append(frame);
    const aborter = new AbortController();
    let result = await new Promise((resolve) => {
      addEventListener("message", ({source, data}) => {
        if (source === frame.contentWindow) {
          aborter.abort();
          resolve(data);
        }
      }, {signal: aborter.signal});
    });
    frame.remove();
    try {
      result = unescapeHtml(result, replacement);
    } catch (code) {
      const _code = code.toString(16).toUpperCase();
      const idx = str.indexOf(String.fromCodePoint(code));
      throw new RangeError(`Unable to encode char U+${_code} at position ${idx}`);
    }
    return byteStringToU8Array(result);
  }

  return encodeText;
})();

// tests
(async () => {
  var str = "中文";
  var charset = "big5";
  var bytes = await encodeText(str, charset, '?');
  console.log(charset, bytes);

  var str = "中文";
  var charset = "shift_jis";
  var bytes = await encodeText(str, charset, '');
  console.log(charset, bytes);

  var str = "中文";
  var charset = "utf-8";
  var bytes = await encodeText(str, charset);
  console.log(charset, bytes);

  var str = "中文";
  var charset = "utf-16be";
  var bytes = await encodeText(str, charset);
  console.log(charset, bytes);

  var str = "中文";
  var charset = "utf-16le";
  var bytes = await encodeText(str, charset);
  console.log(charset, bytes);

  // check special chars are passed safely
  var str = "&#123;<>%20";
  var charset = "big5";
  var bytes = await encodeText(str, charset);
  console.log(charset, bytes);

  // throw an error for a bad charset
  try {
    var str = "中文";
    var charset = "wtf";
    var bytes = await encodeText(str, charset);
  } catch (ex) {
    console.error(ex);
  }

  // throw an error if no replacement string
  try {
    var str = "中文";
    var charset = "big5";
    var bytes = await encodeText(str, charset);
  } catch (ex) {
    console.error(ex);
  }
})();




Many lib still use String methods (fromX/xAt with x:charCode/codePoint)
But this is really slow !
Better approach is to use TextEncoder.
Then you can join utf-8 code units into integer with a little map-filter.
Then you can map integer code point into desired charset.
Key of the map filter is to use N=Math.clz32(~codeUnit<<24)
To get number of code units in sequence from a starting code unit.
If N==0, that is ascii, so accept
If N>=2, that is sequence, consume it (so N--),
   then while N>=1 map in advance,
   until N==0, so accept
To do a map-filter, you have to update the source array before the filter index.
That is, on N==1, do sourceArray[i+1]=codepoint
More generally, on N !==0, accept, else map in advance and filter.
toCodePoints = (s,_)=>[...new TextEncoder().encode(_=0,s)].filter((c,i,a)=>(
  _||(_=Math.clz32(~c<<24), c&=255>>_), _&&_--, // remaining units count
  !_||void(a[i+1]=c<<6|a[i+1]&63) // dont_filter_this or map_in_advance
));

// Test:
randomString = new TextDecoder().decode(new TextEncoder().encode(
  Array.from({length:8761},()=>String.fromCodePoint((1<<20)*Math.random()|0)).join('')
));
expected = Array.from(randomString, c=>c.codePointAt(0));
result = toCodePoints(randomString);
expected.join() === result.join()

For single byte charset:

build a sequence: seq = Uint8Array.from({length:256},(_,i)=>i)
read it: string = new TextDecoder('encoding').decode(seq)
get codes: codes = Array.from(string, (c)=>c.codePointAt(0))
build map: map = new Map(codes.map((c,i)=>[c,i]))

toCodePoints = (s,_=0)=>[...new TextEncoder().encode(s)].filter((c,i,a)=>(
  _||(_=Math.clz32(~c<<24), c&=255>>_),_&&_--,
  !_||void(a[i+1]=c<<6|a[i+1]&63)
));

encoder = (charset)=>{
  const map = new Map([...new TextDecoder(charset).decode(
    Uint8Array.from({length:256},(_,i)=>i)
  )].map((c,i)=>[c.codePointAt(0),i]));
  return {encode: (s)=>toCodePoints(s).map(c=>map.get(c))};
}

// Test:
randomBuffer = Uint8Array.from({length:8761},()=>256*Math.random());
randomString = new TextDecoder('x-mac-cyrillic').decode(randomBuffer);

result = encoder('x-mac-cyrillic').encode(randomString);
randomBuffer.join() === result.join();

